# Как по ключу вложенного словаря вернуть значение основного?

Tags: python, dict

Прошу немного помощи при работе со словарями.
Есть словарь.

```
{'B': {'old': 60691.96, 'now': 61928.03, 'change': 2.04}, 'E': {'old': 4418.98, 'now': 4605.43, 'change': 4.22}, 'D': {'old': 188.5, 'now': 192.49, 'change': 2.12}}
max_percent = 4.22

for xer in global_dict.values():
    if xer['change'] == max_percent:
        print(xer)
        break
    else:
        continue
```

Вывод

```
{'old': 4418.98, 'now': 4605.43, 'change': 4.22}
```

Мне нужно, чтобы ключ возвращался вместе с вложенным словарем. То есть.

```
{'E': {'old': 4418.98, 'now': 4605.43, 'change': 4.22}}
```

Проблема в том, что для поиска ключа, нужно сначала обратиться к элементам значения, сравнить с 4.22, а потом по этому значению вложенного ключа в 'change', вернуть значение словаря, в котором такое значение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

в цикле вместо `values()` используйте `items()`, который содержит информацию и о ключе и о значении, а не только о значении

```
global_dict = {'B': {'old': 60691.96, 'now': 61928.03, 'change': 2.04}, 'E': {'old': 4418.98, 'now': 4605.43, 'change': 4.22}, 'D': {'old': 188.5, 'now': 192.49, 'change': 2.12}}
max_percent = 4.22

for xer in global_dict.items():
    if xer[1]['change'] == max_percent:
        print(xer)
        break
```

Comment: спасибо. работает..